# How to solve Linear Programming Problem with more than one optimal solution using pulp

Tags: python, pulp

I want to solve an LPP which has more than one optimal solution. How can I do that?
For Example:
Maximize 2000x1 + 3000x2

subject to

6x1 + 9x2 ≤ 100
2x1 + x2 ≤ 20

x1, x2 ≥ 0

In this LPP problem, there is more than one optimal solution i.e (0,100/9) and (20/3,20/3). When I solve this problem using the pulp library, it gives me only a (0,100/9) solution. I want all the possible solutions.

Comment: I'm sure there's a better solution, but you could split up your search domain into smaller areas and get the best solution for each sub-domain as a hack

Answer (score 3):

There is a good discusion on this [here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/01/finding-all-optimal-lp-solutions.html).

There are two questions here: (i) How to find multiple optimal solutions to an LP, and (ii) Why you would want to.

Answering (ii) first - typically you might want to ask for all optimal solutions because there is some secondary or lower imporatance objective to pick between them (for example wanting to minimize the change from a current setting, or minimise risk in some way). If this is the case my personal recommendation would be to find a way of incorporating that lower order preference into your objective function (for example by adding in a term with a low weighting).

Answering (i) I find it helps to look at an LP graphically - and the example you have given works nicely for this (two variables means you can plot it - see [plot on wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=6*x1%20%2B%209*x2%20%E2%89%A4%20100%2C%202*x1%20%2B%20x2%20%E2%89%A4%2020%2C%20x1%20%3E%3D%200%2C%20x2%20%3E%3D%200)). Each of your constraints puts a lines on this inequality plot, and solutions can only be chosen on one side of that line.
[image: Inequality plot from Wolfram]

Your objective function is like having a constant gradient across this feasible area and you are trying to find the highest spot. You can draw contours of your objective function by setting it to a specific value and drawing that line. What you'll find if you do this is that your objective function contours are parrallel to the top constraint line (your first constratin).

You can see this directly from the equation: 6x1 + 9x2 <= 100 divides down to 2x1 + 3x2 <= 100/3, and your objective divides down to have the same gradient. What this means is you can move along that top constraint from one corner to the other without changing the value of your objective function.

There are infinitely many optimal solutions which solve the equation:

2x1 + 3x2 == 100/3, between x1==0, and x1==20/3. You have already identified the solutions at the two corners.

If you want to find all the nodes which are equally optimal - for large problems there could be a large number of these - then the code below gives a basic implementation the method discussed [here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/01/finding-all-optimal-lp-solutions.html). When you run it the first time it will give you one of the corner solutions - you then need to add this node (set of variables and slacks which are zero) to A, and iterate until the objective degrades. You could put this within a loop. Note that as currently implemented this only works for problems with variables which have 0 lower bound, and are unbounded above.

```
import pulp as pulp

# Accounting:
# n structural varuables (n = 2)
# m constraints (m = 2)
# => No. of basics = 2 (no. of constraints)
# => No. of non-basics = 2 (no. of variables)

nb = 2
M = 100   # large M value - upper bound for x1, x2 * the slacks

model = pulp.LpProblem('get all basis', pulp.LpMaximize)

# Variables
x = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('x', range(2), lowBound=0, upBound=None, cat='Continuous')

# Non-negative Slack Variables - one for each constraint
s = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('s', range(2), lowBound=0, upBound=None, cat='Continuous')

# Basis variables (binary)
# one for each variable & one for each constraint (& so slack)
B_x = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('b_x', range(len(x)), cat='Binary')
B_s = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('b_s', range(len(s)), cat='Binary')

# Objective
model += 2000*x[0] + 3000*x[1]

# Constraints - with explicit slacks
model += 6*x[0] + 9*x[1] + s[0] == 100
model += 2*x[0] + x[1] + s[1] == 20

# No. of basics is correct:
model += pulp.lpSum(B_x) + pulp.lpSum(B_s) == nb


# Enforce basic and non-basic behaviour
for i in range(len(x)):
    model += x[i] <= M*B_x[i]

for i in range(len(x)):
    model += s[i] <= M*B_s[i]


# Cuts - already discovered solutions
A = []
# A = [[1, 1, 0, 0]]
# A = [[1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1]]

for a in A:
    model += (B_x[0]*a[0] + B_x[1]*a[1] +
              B_s[0]*a[2] + B_s[1]*a[3]) <= nb - 1 

model.solve()

print('Status:', pulp.LpStatus[model.status])
print('Objective:', pulp.value(model.objective))

for v in model.variables():
    print (v.name, "=", v.varValue)
```

Comment: Hi @kabdulla, I found your response quite useful thanks. I am, however, a little confused about how the previous solution is being excluded in the code above. I would appreciate if you could help me to understand how the previous solution is being added to A, or if that isn't happening, how would I achieve this?

Comment: Code above just runs through once - uncommenting one of  two lines which add cuts to `A` would show what the next two iterations would look like. If you want to set this up automatically you would need to get the new elements of `A`, i.,e. `[B_x[0], B_x[1], B_s[0], B_s[1]]` from the previous run and append them to A in a loop. You would also want to check that the objective value has not been degraded (otherwise you've already found all of the optimal solutions).

Comment: Thanks @kabdulla, makes sense now

Comment: Hi again, FYI I tried adapting your really helpful code which is close to working but still became stuck for my particular problem (even though it worked for the case described here). If you're interested, the discussion is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65677194/how-to-solve-for-multiple-solutions-to-linear-program-in-python. Thanks

Comment: @Jwem93 it doesn't work as the method as implemented only works for variables which have 0 lower bound, and are unbounded above. I've added a note to this affect to the answer above. You could re-formulate your problem in terms of variables which meet these requirements.

Comment: Thanks again for your help @kabdulla, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to add a cut to a PuLP LP problem with multiple optimal solutions:

```
from pulp import *
# Define the LP problem
prob = LpProblem("LP Problem", LpMaximize)
# Define variables
x = LpVariable("x", lowBound=0)
y = LpVariable("y", lowBound=0)
# Define an objective function
prob += 2 * x + 3 * y
# Define constraints
prob += x + 2 * y <= 10
prob += x + y <= 5
# Solve the LP problem
prob.solve()
# Check if the LP problem has multiple solutions
if LpStatus[prob.status] == "Optimal":
    if value(x) == 0:
        # Add a cut to eliminate one of the solutions
        prob += x >= 1
        prob.solve()
# Print the result
print("x =", value(x))
print("y =", value(y))
```

In this example, after solving the LP problem, we check if it has an optimal solution and if variable x is equal to 0. If these conditions are true, it means that the problem has multiple solutions. To eliminate one of the solutions, we add a cut that requires variable x to be greater than or equal to 1. We then solve the LP problem again, and this time we should obtain a unique solution.